# javascript Data URI charset when saving

Tags: javascript, data-uri

I am using something like this in a utf-8 page:

```
var data = "a\tb\tc\r\nd\te\tf";
window.location.href = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(data);
```

to force the browser to download the text and save it. I works fine except that when I open the file in excel it does not open correctly (it neither reads the separator nor the arabic characters).. I need to "import data" to specify that the file is UTF-8, when I do this it works correctly... When I open the file in notepad and resave it in unicode... it works correctly. Is there a way to force it to save in unicode from the start? or make the csv file open correctly in excel.

I tried to change it to "charset=utf-16" but it didn't work.

PS: I cannot change the page character set.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need, a small addon:

```
'data:text/csv;charset=utf8,' + '\uFEFF' + encodeURIComponent(csv)
```

this addon ('\uFEFF') makes it real "UTF-8", without it, it would be: "UTF-8 w/o BOM"

Comment: Thank you :) this was really useful

Answer (score 1):

What your JS code produces is

```
a    b   c 
 d   e  f
```

But the valid should be

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

in code

```
var data = "a,b,c\r\nd,e,f";
```

---

or in **tab-delimited format**

```
a    b    c
d    e    f
```

in code

```
var data = "a\tb\tc\r\nd\te\tf";
```

---

CSV is a short of **Comma-separated values**

- http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: I cannot use the comma because I have number values with commas in it.

Comment: And I can use ";" it will be separated correctly but the arabic characters won't be read.

Comment: @AhHatem you can use tab-separated (see part 2 of my answer), and about reading, are you sure it's problem of saving and not reading the UTF16 data?

Comment: @AhHatem or it can be problem of in which charset is saved the code of page, check it

Comment: I am sorry  don't understand what you mean by: "charset is saved the code of page"

Comment: in which charset does your text editor (eg. Netbeans) save the javascript code.

Comment: Actually, this code is saved and run as bookmark, so there is no js file